# Unable to acces twitter.com website

Tags: proxy, twitter

I can't access twitter.com. I don't know why.
Is it due to proxy or other things?

[image: https://www.upsieutoc.com/image/pjP7]

Comment: You mean, your corporate admin allows you to access the Internet via a proxy which prevents access to Twitter, and you need help circumventing it ?

Comment: Where are you from? Vietnam? Do you already know http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/ ?

Comment: Please open a terminal, run `host twitter.com` and `host twitter.com 8.8.8.8` and post their output. Your ISP probably blocks that domain name for political reasons.

Answer (score 0):

here are your possible solutions:

if you can't access the server (website) firstly try to ping it to get response:

```
ping twitter.com -c4
```

you must get e.g.:

```
ping twitter.com -c4
PING twitter.com (199.16.156.6) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 199.16.156.6: icmp_seq=1 ttl=246 time=134 ms
64 bytes from 199.16.156.6: icmp_seq=2 ttl=246 time=132 ms
64 bytes from 199.16.156.6: icmp_seq=3 ttl=246 time=133 ms
64 bytes from 199.16.156.6: icmp_seq=4 ttl=246 time=133 ms

--- twitter.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3005ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 132.808/133.499/134.014/0.629 ms
```

that means everything is ok.

Other solutions install `tor`

```
sudo apt-get install tor
```

Then in Mozilla go to edit/preferences/advanced/network/settings choose manual proxy and enter in the Host tab `127.0.0.1` and port `9050` and press ok. Done.

Or install Tor-Browser bundle:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/tor-browser

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install tor-browser
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install wine, and after then download freegate and run it by wine to bypass filtering if any. I recommend you don't install Tor because it doesn't work correctly.